# Why xargs cannnot receive input parameters through pipe?

Tags: mqtt

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS  Shell

1.

```
mosquitto_sub -h 192.168.1.3 -t "application/2/device/df9cde4119c814ef/rx" -v
application/2/device/df9cde4119c814ef/rx {"applicationID":"2","applicationName":"E78","deviceName":"E78-DTU","devEUI":"35zeQRnIFO8=","rxInfo":[],"txInfo":{"frequenation":"LORA","loRaModulationInfo":{"bandwidth":125,"spreadingFactor":9,"codeRate":"4/5","polarizationInversion":false}},"adr":false,"dr":3,"fCnt":15,"fPort":65,"dectJSON":"","tags":{}}
```

2. ```
   (mosquitto_sub -h 192.168.1.3 -t "application/2/device/df9cde4119c814ef/rx" -v)|grep dev
   application/2/device/df9cde4119c814ef/rx {"applicationID":"2","applicationName":"E78","deviceName":"E78-DTU","devEUI":"35zeQRnIFO8=","rxInfo":[],"txInfo":{"frequenation":"LORA","loRaModulationInfo":{"bandwidth":125,"spreadingFactor":9,"codeRate":"4/5","polarizationInversion":false}},"adr":false,"dr":3,"fCnt":47,"fPort":65,"dectJSON":"","tags":{}}
   ```
3. ```
   (mosquitto_sub -h 192.168.1.3 -t "application/2/device/df9cde4119c814ef/rx" -v)|cat
   application/2/device/df9cde4119c814ef/rx {"applicationID":"2","applicationName":"E78","deviceName":"E78-DTU","devEUI":"35zeQRnIFO8=","rxInfo":[],"txInfo":{"frequenation":"LORA","loRaModulationInfo":{"bandwidth":125,"spreadingFactor":9,"codeRate":"4/5","polarizationInversion":false}},"adr":false,"dr":3,"fCnt":36,"fPort":65,"dectJSON":"","tags":{}}
   ```
4. ```
   (mosquitto_sub -h 192.168.1.3 -t "application/2/device/df9cde4119c814ef/rx" -v)|awk '{print $1; fflush()}'
   ```
5. ```
   (mosquitto_sub -h 192.168.1.3 -t "application/2/device/df9cde4119c814ef/rx" -v)|xargs
   ```

In 1,2,3，the shell command can output normally.
But in 4,5, the shell command can output nothing.Why?

how to fix 4,5 to output normally?

Comment: This is off topic, it would probably be best asked on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/). (p.s. the reason will be because mosquitto_sub doesn't return, it hold stdout open continues to write new messages to it forever. `awk` will wait to read the whole output in before outputting.

Comment: There are dedicated cli tool to run a command on a MQTT message